# What is 'anxiety'?

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-meaning

English is my second language and I don't live in an english speaking country, so my exposure to native speakers is rather low. I often see the term 'sth. triggers my anxiety' (e.g. this [workplace question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/146846/what-is-the-best-way-of-dealing-with-a-work-colleague-who-triggers-my-anxiety) in which OP says 'constantly triggers my anxiety' about a co-worker).

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiety), 'anxiety' is a medical condition, but in most use cases, it sounds like it's rather used to describe generally awkward or uncomfortable situations.

Similarly in [this blog](https://www.thehealthy.com/mental-health/anxiety/weird-anxiety-causes/) ('19 Everyday Things That Could Trigger Anxiety'), in which 'You’re thirsty' is mentioned as one reason of experiencing anxiety.

So is 'anxiety' (currently?) an umbrella term for many different negative feeling?

Answer (score 1):

The word *anxiety* is similar to *depression* in that its meaning in general speech is much broader than its meaning as a medical term.

In general, every day speech [anxiety](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/anxiety) means

> A feeling of worry, nervousness, or unease about something with an uncertain outcome.

So, for example, you can say that *waiting for your exam results is causing you some anxiety* without it meaning that you're suffering from a medical complaint.

There is another non-medical meaning, where it represents a

> Strong desire or concern to do something or for something to happen

For example, you could say that *you were anxious for those exam results to arrive* which would mean that you were eager for them to arrive rather than you were worried about them arriving.

Answer (score 0):

In the medical science, it is related to the functioning of mind. Anxiety is a neuro problem if it continuously interferes with one's life. But one's anxiety about security in a terror-prone area, or about exam score after writing an exam not so well, is just normal.

Anxiety, depression, stress, OCD etc are related.  Many people have it, and they usually manage it. It could be genetic, and sometimes due to insecurity, bad experiences in childhood etc.

In case of Neuro problem (neurosis), the affected has insight into what he/she is suffering from, unlike psycho problems (psychosis) where the affected is unaware of what is happening to him/her.

Comment: Showing your research enhances your answer.

Comment: edit that in to your answer